# Vanishing torsion condition preserved when doing a connexion transformation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I have a simple question but I can't wrap my head around it.

First let's consider a Riemannian manifold with a metric $g$ with an affin Connection $ \Gamma $

If we want to construct a Levi-Civita Connexion we surely need to impose

1. A metricity condition $\nabla g=0$

This gives us a way (let's say) to decompose the connection into two parts one symmetric depending on the metric and a second part antisymmetric depending on something we call torsion.

2. The second condition is the vanishing torsion $T=0$. The purpose of it is well known and trivial.

My question is on the second condition: if we want to impose it locally on a point, the connection would change to Christoffel symbols. But how do we know that this condition is preserved in all the manifold?

My guess to the answer is in the fact that a connection is decomposable, as I mentioned earlier, into two parts this makes the two parts transform independently from each other. So if the first part (the symmetric part) transform non covariantly the second part transform tensorially, to ensure the fact that a connection transforms non covariantly. And because the torsion is tensorial we can say that the condition is preserved. I still feel that my reasoning is a little bit wrong. Tell me what you think.

**EDIT**:

Let's consider an affine connection $\Gamma$ in a (pseudo)-Riemannian manifold M of dimension 4 and a point $x\in M$ in a neighbourhood $U \subset M$ and finally a chart.
These considerations will associate to each point a connection $\Gamma$ that will transport vectors of tangent spaces from one point to another neighbourhood $V$.

If we impose the metricity condition on $x$ we will,  as I said, decompose the connection into

$$\Gamma^\mu_{\ \nu\rho}= \widetilde{\Gamma}^\mu_{\ \nu\rho}(g, \partial g)+ K^\mu_{\ \nu\rho}(T)$$
Where $\widetilde{\Gamma}^\mu_{\ \nu\rho}$ are the Christoffel symbols and $K^\mu_{\ \nu\rho}(T)$ is what we call contortion.

So if we impose a torsion-free condition on $x$ and transport a vector from $x$ to $y \in V$. we need to be sure that the condition $T=0$ is still verified. Hence doing a transformation on the equation $T=0$ and noticing that it's tensorial will ensure that it's verfied everywhere in the manifold. And besides that, a transformation on the Christoffel symbols does not generate a part with torsion because first, they depend on $g$ and second the inhomogeneous part of the transformation is symmetric.

Comment: Im not sure those words “simple question” mean what you think they mean, 

Comment: So the antisymmetric part (torsion) of connexion will transform as tensor, while symmetric part (Christoffel) transform as an object of Jet Bundle (symmetry of indices are maintained in this transformation)

Comment: Torsion being tensorial isn't related. We enforce the condition (symmetric affine connection) *everywhere* for the full geometry, not just at a point.

Comment: @Eletie I thought about it and it's a correct way to doing it, but it's not a construction in the proper sense, at least for me. I want to be able to say that the condition of vanishing torsion is preserved when doing a transformation on the connection.

Comment: @KP99 Am sorry, I don't correctly know what's a Jet bundle but it seems that my guess was right ... or it was not?

Comment: Your final conclusion under 'Edit' section is correct. See : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87524/which-vector-bundle-are-the-christoffel-symbols-sections-of